# Access one web api controller from another

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web, asp.net-web-api

I have two web api controllers: `PageController` and `BlogController`. They contain simple crud for creating pages and blogs. Every time I create a blog, I need to create a page, but not vice versa. Whats the best way of doing this? I feel like something weird must happen with my routing if I inherit from `PageController` in `BlogController`. Is there some way to call the `CreatePage` method in `PageController` from `BlogController`'s `CreateBlog` method? Should I simply resign myself to making two separate ajax calls every time I want to create a blog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are going to need to have some common logic that needs to be accessed by multiple controllers you should create a separate class to handle that common logic in a centralized manner.

This class can be part of your web project or in a separate project/assembly.

Basically what you are trying to do is this:

```
public class BlogController
{
    public void CreateBlog()
    {
        var pc = new PageController();
        pc.CreatePage();
    }
}
public class PageController
{
    private Database db;
    public void CreatePage()
    {
        var page = new Page();
        db.SavePage(page);
    }
}
```

And I am suggesting that you do this:

```
public class BlogController
{
    public void CreateBlog()
    {
        Blog.CreatePage();
    }
}
public class PageController
{
    public void CreatePage()
    {
        Blog.CreatePage();
    }
}
public class Blog
{
    private Database db;
    public static void CreatePage() // does not 
    {
        var page = new Page();
        db.SavePage(page);
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean, the common logic would basically be the entirety of the PageController, minus a few routing attributes. I can certainly see how it would work fine, but I wonder if this is the "right" way to do this.

Comment: The `right way` would be separating the logic that receives/handles the request (the controller) from the logic that actually processes the request. I suggest moving that logic out of both controller methods and placing it in a dedicated business object.

Comment: What about when you cannot refactor out the logic into a dedicated business object?  Eg, Say BlogController and PageController derive from MyControllerBase which you do not own and you must use protected method calls in your public actions.  There is no way to create a business object like you described.

Comment: @MPavlak that sounds somewhat related but not exactly, could you please post this as a separate question and link to it here? This way you can clearly convey the issue you're having and I or someone else can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create object of the controller and then use the respective functions.