# HTTP API operations calling each other

Tags: c#, api, rest

Is it ok/acceptable to re-use public API operation between methods?

Say I have one method (GET api/something) and in that method I call internal (GET api/somethingElse).

Internally meaning I instantiate the class and call the method.

Comment: In general there's nothing wrong with instantiating a class and invoking a method on that class.  Whether or not it's a good idea in your particular case, we can't know without knowing more about your structure.  It's *uncommon* for controller methods to invoke other controller methods, usually they invoke common backing logic instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@David says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053814/http-api-operations-calling-each-other#comment52006627_32053814) and as explained in [Access one web api controller from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210043/access-one-web-api-controller-from-another), [Call WebApi controller from another controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485765/call-webapi-controller-from-another-controller), and so on, you shouldn't instantiate controllers in controllers.

An HTTP API is (supposed to be) just a very thin layer to map an HTTP request to business logic, perhaps performing some authentication and authorization along the way.

A typical GET method in an API controller should look like this:

```
public SomeModel Get(int id)
{
    var model = _repository.Get(id);
    return model;
}
```

So if you do this:

```
public SomeModel Get(int id)
{
    var database = new Database();
    var record = database.SomeModels.Get(id);
    record.FooProperty = DoSomeLogic();

    // and so on

    return record;
}
```

And in another method `GetSomethingElse`, maybe even in an other controller, you want to access this logic, then you should look into abstracting everything that happens in this method into a separate class, in my former code referenced through the `_repository` variable.

Then you can reuse the logic between controllers and action methods.

Comment: I think all the comments clarified and acknowledging my feelings, thx for example

Comment: Just trying to emphasize this point: Web Service API is just a public access point that configures routing, authentication/authorization, and some other Web Service specific actions to a business layer - commonly a Class Library API. The Class Library API has no restrictions on access or routing, which is why a Web Service API is needed.